# Transcendental equation solutions

Tags: roots, graphing-functions

I'm working on solving a 3d particle in a well for quantum mechanics.

I have the transcendental equation
$$ - \cot(z) = \sqrt{(z_0/z)^2-1} $$

A graph of this looks like

```
Plot[{Sqrt[(5*\[Pi]/z)^2 - 1], -Cot[z]}, {z, 0, 5*\[Pi]}]
```

[image]

A solution manual for Griffiths QM book states that the solutions ONLY occur at multiples of pi, and supplies the following graph

[image]

why are those other non-intervals of pi intersections not considered?

Comment: Can you rprovide a reference to the solutions manual?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici this 5 pi is arbitrary no? 10 pi just extends things

Comment: @NickD Solution manual to David Griffith's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 2nd ed.

Comment: @LopeyTall After solving for $z_0$, you require the inverse of $z\csc(z)$. See [Kepler equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation)

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you are looking for the zero's of function
$$f(z)=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{z^2}-1}+\cot (z)$$ You cannot have any solution if $z \gt a$.

Concerning the possible roots, using Taylor expansion around $z=k \pi$ and series reversion, they are given by
$$z_{(k)}=k \pi \left(1-\frac{1}{\left(a^2-\pi ^2 k^2\right)^{1/2}}+\frac{\pi ^2 k^2}{2 \left(a^2-\pi ^2 k^2\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{a^2}{\left(a^2-\pi ^2 k^2\right)^2} +\cdots\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

If that's what the manual says, it is wrong.  Multiples of $\pi$ are not solutions, as $\cot$ is not defined there.  Rather, there is one solution in each interval between two multiples of $\pi$.